# Update existing SharePoint list from Excel file in library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-flow

What I'm trying to do is to update the SharePoint list if there is an item in the Excel file that is not in SharePoint, for example

I have in the SharePoint list one item:

| PR Number | Desc | Title | Priority | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0005689 | lorem | example | (This is a dropdown) | http://example.com |

And in the Excel I have three items:

| Number | Desc | Title | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0005689 | lorem | example | http://example.com |
| 0003491 | lorem | example | http://example.com |
| 0001497 | lorem | example | http://example.com |

So basically I want to compare if each of the Number values in the Excel file exists in the SharePoint list, and if not, then add it to SharePoint so the final list will be like:

| PR Number | Desc | Title | Priority | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0005689 | lorem | example | (This is a dropdown) | http://example.com |
| 0003491 | lorem | example | (This is a dropdown) | http://example.com |
| 0001497 | lorem | example | (This is a dropdown) | http://example.com |

So far I have tried with PowerAutomate (MS Flow) but it is quite confusing how to use it, I have just being able to set the recurrence to each day, and to get the items and the worksheet, but I don't find a way to handle the data and make the comparisson nor the addition to the list.

I did my research in the forum but the threads are more than 7 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the screenshots for a sample Power Automate below.

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Matiur, this does the trick. I just do not find where to put the recurrence control.